# Join separator ignored Python

Tags: string, join

I'm new to Python and attempting some exercises for learning.
The exercise I am stuck on involves taking a sentence and changing the first letter of each word to uppercase.
I'm almost there apart from one last snag I just can't figure out.

The sentence in question is 'how can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real'
The output I require is 'How Can Mirrors Be Real If Our Eyes Aren't Real'

However, what I am getting is 'HowCanMirrorsBeRealIfOurEyesAren'tReal'

I am preceding the the call to join() with " " but this is not inserting a gap between in word.

```
    s = "how can mirrors be real if our eyes aren't real"
    words = s.split()
    sentence = ""
    for word in words:
        sentence += " ".join([word]).capitalize()

    print sentence
```

Comment: The list you're giving to `join()` only has a single entry... What do you expect it to do when you don't actually give it two or more items to join? Perhaps `" ".join([word.capitalize() for word in words])` is closer to what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: That achieved what I was after (thanks), although in the end I used the string capwords() function.